# run js function on dynamically created select menu

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have this code:

This is the addOptions function

```
<script>
var values = <?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM billing_sagenominalcodes order by code ASC";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$nominalcodes = array();
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $nominalcodes[] = $result['code'];
}
echo json_encode($nominalcodes);
?>;
var names = <?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM billing_sagenominalcodes order by code ASC";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$nominalcodesname = array();
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $nominalcodesname[] = $result['code'] . ' - ' . $result['name'];
}
echo json_encode($nominalcodesname);
?>;
function addOptions(select, values)
{
    for (var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++)
    {
        select.appendChild(new Option(names[i],values[i]));
     }
}
</script>
```

then the add row function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
function addRow()
{
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

          var sagenominalcodeCell = row.insertCell(3);
          var elSageNominalCode = document.createElement('select');
          elSageNominalCode.type = 'select';
          elSageNominalCode.name = 'sagenominalcode' + i;
          elSageNominalCode.id = 'sagenominalcode' + i;
          sagenominalcodeCell.appendChild(elSageNominalCode);
 i++;
 }
 </script>
```

and then the HTML

```
<select name="sagenominalcode" id="sagenominalcode">
        <script>addOptions(document.getElementById('sagenominalcode'), values);</script>
        </select>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" />
```

it adds the new rows ok but its no populating the select menu with the addOptions function.

is there any way to make it run that function once the new row/select menu has been dynamically created and then the same for all the others created when the addRow function is called?

Answer (score 1):

So, reading your code a little bit more, I see you have

```
new Option(names[i],values[i])
```

My question to you is what does `new Option` return? I don't see code for it anywhere in your question.
Take a look at the spec for appendChild :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild

It needs an `element` passed in. What you want to do is make a new element using the `createElement()` function like so:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
```

And then edit the inner html to be what ever you need like this:

option.innerHTML = "your option content here";

Then pass the element in to the append child function:

appendChild(option);

<strike>Use jQuery here instead of straight js. My bet is that your listener for click is only bound to the items that are present on the page when it is created. If you set up a listener through jQuery, then it will fire even on components that are dynamically added.</strike>

Also from a code structuring stand point, be very careful about writing js with php. Although it sounds fun (like doing drugs in highschool) it is dangerous, frustrating and leads to untestable code (like doing drugs in highschool does).

Comment: ah right okk - i will have a look into that. do you know the way to get it working in javascript for now?